# How do I get Zsh completion to work in the old way?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm not a fan of the smart completion system and I just want it to work as in the old days. How do I get zsh to autocomplete in the old way? E.g. autocompleting all commands in my PATH and all files (and directories) in my current dir. I don't want any kind of smart intelligence.

What I have tried:

- No zle or zstyle configuration commands in my ~/.zshrc file. This results in smart completion, e.g. typing 'cd ' will complete only directories (yes, I want it to be dumb and complete everything, including files)
- This configuration in .zshrc:

  ```
    zle -C complete-file complete-word _generic
    zstyle ':completion:complete-file::::' completer _files
  ```

  This completes files but command completion is lost.

The documentation is just overwhelming and I can't seem to find any quick hack to just disable the smart completion system alltogether.

Edit:

Running zmodload -L gives me the following result:

```
$ zmodload -L
zmodload zsh/complete
zmodload zsh/computil
zmodload zsh/main
zmodload zsh/parameter
zmodload zsh/stat
zmodload zsh/terminfo
zmodload zsh/zle
zmodload zsh/zutil
```

Do I need zsh/complete and zsh/computil for normal completion to work? I'm not running any zmodload commands from my ~/.zshrcf-file and grep -r zmodload /etc/zsh* returns nothing.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Do you have some modules like oh-my-zsh loaded? Programmable completion is not turned on by default in the `zsh` shell...

Comment: I haven't installed oh-my-zsh. I updated my question to include the output of zmodload -L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `compinit`. That's all you need to do. You might have the call in your `.zshrc` file, or perhaps another dotfile, or perhaps you source a plugin that calls it. Find out where it gets called and then remove the call. If `compinit` never gets called, then you'll get the old skool completion system instead.

If you can't find where `compinit` is called, try running `zsh -x 2>zsh.log` (exit the shell as soon as you see the prompt) then look for the `compinit` call in `zsh.log`

> Do I need zsh/complete and zsh/computil for normal completion to work?

Yes, you do need `zsh/complete` and `zsh/computil`, if you want any completion at all.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helped! running "zsh -x 2>zsh.log" helped me to track down the problem to the file /etc/zsh/zshrc. How wonderful it is to have it working in the old way again. :)